# https - How to enable users to have secure connection with Jenkins via ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, jenkins, https, dockerfile

Below is the cloud formation template that creates Elastic Load Balancer as public facing to jenkins(`jenkins:ecs` docker) running in VPC subnet:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Jenkins Stack",
    "Parameters":{
        "VpcId": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
            "Description": "The target VPC Id"

        },
        "SubnetId": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id",
            "Description": "The target subnet Id"
        },
        "KeyName": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "The key pair that is allowed SSH access"
        }
    },
    "Resources":{
        "EC2Instance":{
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Properties":{
                "ImageId": "ami-05958d7635caa4d04",
                "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
                "SubnetId": { "Ref": "SubnetId"},
                "KeyName": { "Ref": "KeyName"},
                "SecurityGroupIds": [ { "Ref": "EC2InstanceSecurityGroup"} ],
                "IamInstanceProfile": { "Ref" : "EC2InstanceProfile"},
                "UserData":{
                    "Fn::Base64": { "Fn::Join": ["", [
                        "#!/bin/bash\n",
                        "echo ECS_CLUSTER=", { "Ref": "EcsCluster" }, " >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config\n",
                        "groupadd -g 1000 jenkins\n",
                        "useradd -u 1000 -g jenkins jenkins\n",
                        "mkdir -p /ecs/jenkins_home\n",
                        "chown -R jenkins:jenkins /ecs/jenkins_home\n"
                    ] ] }
                },
                "Tags": [ { "Key": "Name", "Value": { "Fn::Join": ["", [ { "Ref": "AWS::StackName"}, "-instance" ] ]} }]
            }
        },
        "EC2InstanceSecurityGroup":{
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "GroupDescription": { "Fn::Join": ["", [ { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" }, " ingress security group" ] ] },
                "VpcId": { "Ref": "VpcId" },
                "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                    {
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "FromPort": "8080",
                        "ToPort": "8080",
                        "SourceSecurityGroupId": { "Ref": "ElbSecurityGroup"}
                    },
                    {
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "FromPort": "22",
                        "ToPort": "22",
                        "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                    }
                ],
                "Tags": [ { "Key": "Name", "Value": { "Fn::Join": ["", [ { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" }, "-ec2-sg" ] ] } } ]
            }
        },
        "EC2InstanceProfile": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
            "Properties": {
                "Path": "/",
                "Roles": [ { "Ref": "EC2InstanceRole" } ]
            }
        },
        "EC2InstanceRole": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "Properties": {
                "AssumeRolePolicyDocument":{
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": { "Service": [ "ec2.amazonaws.com" ] },
                            "Action": [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Path": "/",
                "ManagedPolicyArns": [ "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role" ]
            }
        },
        "ElbSecurityGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "GroupDescription": { "Fn::Join": ["", [ { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" }, " ELB ingress security group" ] ] },
                "VpcId": { "Ref": "VpcId"},
                "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                    {
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "FromPort": "80",
                        "ToPort": "80",
                        "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                    }
                ],
                "Tags": [ { "Key": "Name", "Value": { "Fn::Join": ["", [ { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" }, "-elb-sg" ] ] } } ]
            }
        },
        "ElasticLoadBalancer": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
            "Properties": {
                "CrossZone": "false",
                "SecurityGroups": [ { "Ref": "ElbSecurityGroup" } ],
                "Listeners": [
                    {
                        "LoadBalancerPort": "80",
                        "InstancePort": "8080",
                        "Protocol": "http"
                    }

                ],
                "Instances": [ { "Ref": "EC2Instance"} ],
                "Subnets": [ { "Ref": "SubnetId"} ]
            }
        },
        "EcsCluster": {
            "Type": "AWS::ECS::Cluster"
        },
        "EcsTaskDefinition": {
            "Type": "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition",
            "Properties": {
                "ContainerDefinitions": [
                    {
                        "Name": "jenkins",
                        "Image": "somedockeracct/jenkins:ecs",
                        "Memory": 500,
                        "PortMappings": [ 
                            { 
                                "ContainerPort": 8080, 
                                "HostPort": 8080 
                            },
                            { 
                                "ContainerPort": 50000, 
                                "HostPort": 50000 
                            }
                        ],
                        "MountPoints": [
                            {
                                "SourceVolume": "docker",
                                "ContainerPath": "/var/run/docker.sock"
                            },
                            {
                                "SourceVolume": "jenkins_home",
                                "ContainerPath": "/var/jenkins_home"
                            }
                        ]
                    }


                ],
                "Volumes": [
                    {
                        "Name": "jenkins_home",
                        "Host": { "SourcePath": "/ecs/jenkins_home" }
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "docker",
                        "Host": { "SourcePath": "/var/run/docker.sock" }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "EcsService": {
            "Type": "AWS::ECS::Service",
            "Properties": {
                "Cluster": { "Ref": "EcsCluster" },
                "TaskDefinition": { "Ref": "EcsTaskDefinition" },
                "DesiredCount": 1
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs":{
        "ElbDomainName": {
            "Description": "Public DNS name of Elastic Load Balancer",
            "Value": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "ElasticLoadBalancer",
                    "DNSName"
                ]
            }
        },
        "EC2InstanceDomainName": {
            "Description": "Public DNS name of EC2 instance",
            "Value": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "EC2Instance",
                    "PublicDnsName"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

where the docker file of jenkins master(`jenkins:ecs`) is:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.190.2

MAINTAINER Developer team <devteam@abc.com>

# Suppress apt installation warnings
# https://serverfault.com/a/227194/220043
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Official Jenkins image does not include sudo, change to root user
USER root

# Used to set the docker group ID
# Set to 497 by default, which is the groupID used by AWS Linux ECS instance
ARG DOCKER_GID=497

# Create Docker Group with GID
# Set default value of 497 if DOCKER_GID set to blank string by Docker compose
RUN groupadd -g ${DOCKER_GID:-497} docker

# Install base packages for docker, docker-compose & ansible
# apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys AA8E81B4331F7F50 && \
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get -y install bc \
                    gawk \
                    libffi-dev \
                    musl-dev \
                    apt-transport-https \
                    curl \
                    python3 \
                    python3-dev \
                    python3-setuptools \
                    gcc \
                    make \
                    libssl-dev \
                    python3-pip 

# Used at build time but not runtime
ARG DOCKER_VERSION=18.06.1~ce~3-0~debian

# Install the latest Docker CE binaries and add user `jenkins` to the docker group
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg-agent \
    software-properties-common && \
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID")/gpg > /tmp/dkey; apt-key add /tmp/dkey && \
    add-apt-repository \
      "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID") \
      $(lsb_release -cs) \
      stable" && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install docker-ce=${DOCKER_VERSION:-18.06.1~ce~3-0~debian}  && \
        # docker-ce-cli=${DOCKER_VERSION:-18.06.1~ce~3-0~debian} \
        # containerd.io && \
    usermod -aG docker jenkins

ARG DOCKER_COMPOSE=1.24.1

# Install docker compose
RUN curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/${DOCKER_COMPOSE:-1.24.1}/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" \
    -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && \
    pip3 install ansible boto3

# Change to jenkins user
USER jenkins

# Add jenkins plugin
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
```

---

Master jenkins docker container runs in EC2(docker host).

In this scenario, ELB is not used for load balancing but to public face Jenkins. Currently ELB is connected using `http`

---

How to enable `https` secure connection to jenkins via ELB?

Which component holds the responsibility to ensure secure connection? ELB or Jenkins

Answer (score 3):

Try setting up SSL certificates on the ELB using AWS ACM. Once that is done, create a secure listener for https on the ELB and forward that traffic to the http port of Jenkins using the steps mentioned below:

**AWS ACM**

- Navigate to AWS ACM and click on "Request a Certificate" button.
- Select "Request a public certificate" option
- Add domain names for which the certificate is required
- Choose "DNS validation" for certificate validation
- Add tags(optional) and Review and Confirm
- If you are using AWS route53 for your DNS then there is a button which automatically creates the CNAME entries for your certificate in route53. If you are using any other DNS then make sure that you create the CNAME records as mentioned by ACM.
- After the CNAME record is verified on the DNS, your ACM certificate status will change from "Pending" to "Issued"

**AWS ELB - Classic Load Balancer**

- Add a new listener to the load balancer with the below mentioned details:

  - Load Balancer Protocol: HTTPS(Secure HTTP)
  - Load Balancer Port: 443
  - Instance Protocol: HTTP
  - Instance Port: 8080(or any other port you have configured Jenkins)

**AWS ELB - Application Load Balancer**

- In case if you are using ALB, then create a Target group with Target type: Instance, Protocol: HTTP, Port: 8080

In case you face any issues in health checks, ensure that your security groups are allowing traffic on port 8080 from the ELB/ALB.

Another way would be to install nginx on the server and use the below listed configuration for the server file(In this case change 8080 to 80 in the ELB/ALB configuration mentioned above):

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name xxx.xxx.xxx;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-request-public.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-listener-config.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html

Comment: Yes, I have done some review on AWS ACM for generating ssl certificates. But can you elaborate more on the process of "create a secure listener for https on the ELB and forward that traffic", I need some reference to read on this

Comment: I have eddited the answer with detailed steps. Also refer to the AWS docs mentioned at the end